# git grep: Where is "binary file" in match?

Tags: git, git-grep

I'm looking for something that may have been committed in a Git repository. I'm using a command like the following:

```
git grep ABCD `git rev-list --all`
```

and getting output like

```
Binary file 9246a896bf37856f37d424dbcb40d14a51b6b315:blah-blah-blah-ABCD-blah-blah matches
Binary file 083407e0ea97796054f614c28808ae9a4fcf2fe8:blah-blah-blah-ABCD-blah-blah matches
```

How can I find the commit or commits that this relates to?

Answer (score 3):

You have it right in front of you: `9246a896bf37856f37d424dbcb40d14a51b6b315` is the commit, and `blah-blah-blah-ABCD-blah-blah` is the file name.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for that hex string using `git log --branches=*` and didn't find it, so assumed it mustn't be a commit id. But `git log -r 9246a896bf37856f37d424dbcb40d14a51b6b315` shows what I wanted.